# How do pass a dynamic value to pfquery?

Tags: ios, ios7, parse-platform

How do you pass a dynamic value to a parse query from a plist, the below code does not retrieve any data?

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"filter" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
self.featured = [dict objectForKey:@"Featured"];
self.percentageHigh = [dict objectForKey:@"PercentageHigh"];
self.percentageLow = [dict objectForKey:@"PercentageLow"];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
[query whereKey:@"dsPercentage" lessThanOrEqualTo:self.percentageHigh];
```

Comment: i had to remove the "self" and call the variable with an underscore

Comment: You must learn to use NSLog statements as you work.  Add NSLog(@"self.parseClassName .. %@", self.parseClassName); just before the query statement.  Do not remove the "self.".  **Look** in your .h file, it's possible you are doing something wrong there.